# PHP 7 syntax error -> wrong operator when trying to upgrade from PHP5.6

Tags: php, syntax, php-7

Trying to replace a deprecated line with:

```
if (new My_Model())->_caching($class)
```

This broke the PHP7 app with the operator " -> "

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

I used above line when trying to replace:

```
if (self::_caching($class))
```

which was incorrectly produces a non-static method.

```
static function search($class,
                       $table,
                       $search_options,
                       $sql_options = array(),
                       $limit = -1,
                       $offset = 0)
{
    $ci = &get_instance();      
    $tenant_id = $ci->tenant->id;

    if (self::_caching($class))
    {
        // Check cache first
        $cached_objects_key = $class.'-'.md5(serialize($search_options).
                                serialize($sql_options).$limit.$offset);
        if ($cached_keys = $ci->cache->get($cached_objects_key, $class, $tenant_id))
        {
            $cached_objects = array();
            foreach ($cached_keys as $object_cache_key)
            {
                if ($cached_object = $ci->cache->get($object_cache_key, $class, $tenant_id))
                {
                    array_push($cached_objects, $cached_object);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // we can't complete the list, so break out
                    // and let the function continue
                    unset($cached_objects);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

This question was posed for discussing operator -> error and how to remove. Not immediately having to do with referencing arrays.

Comment: Read about the [`if` control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). The condition must stay between parentheses.

Comment: you have a closing bracket in the wrong place, it should read `if (new My_Model()->_caching($class))`... but why are you changing the code? the static method `_caching()` should still work in php7! I think you should go back a step and if you had a problem then ask the question that motivated you to make this change

Comment: `if ((new My_Model())->_caching($class))`

Comment: Wee Zel - The app breaks in PHP7 with the self method above. It's deprecated for v7. If you have a better idea how it can be replaced, would love to see it. Thanks.

Comment: did it say something like "Deprecated: Non-static method My_Model::_caching() should not be called statically"??

Comment: yes Wee Zel that's right

Comment: u_mulder's line seemed to work best . . .

Comment: if the declaration for the `_caching()` function is declared as `private function` (I expect it is, old style coding used the underscore to represent private functions) then change it to `private static function`. then revert other changes you have made and everything should be fine

Comment: Miken32  please refer to last line in OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `if (new My_Model())->_caching($class)`

Into: `if ((new My_Model())->_caching($class))`

You tried to acces the function on the if statement instead of the class.

Comment: edited the answer as pointed out by @u_mulder